# In Stata data browser how do you convert string display to corresponding integers?

Tags: string, str-replace, stata

In Stata (v12), I have a variable which, in the data browser or editor window, is displaying integer values of the variable as text.  For example:

```
90 kg bag
90 kg bag
handfuls
.25
90 kg bag
.1
.1
numbers
gorogoro
tonnes
.25
.01
90 kg bag
90 kg bag
kg
.2
.05
.05
litre
```

Wherever you see text in the column above there should be an integer value.  (This is probably due to a mistake made by the people who compiled the data file.) Stata is reading the integers as a sort of code that refers to those strings.  How do I get Stata to display the integers instead of the text?

Comment: It's quite confusing to me what are you asking here for?The column has text so obviously Stata will not read those as integers. Do you want replace only texts with `.`?

Comment: @Metrics Again, this column appears in the data browser spreadsheet.  It is not something that appears in the do file command dialogue.

Comment: Did you transfer this file to a Stata file or was this given to you as a Stata file?

Answer (score 0):

You are very likely looking at the value labels of a numeric variable. Use

```
 . edit, nolabel
```

to check and also use `describe` to get basic information on the variable. For from being a mistake, its coding was probably deliberate.

Comment: Variable name is "acres", so clearly it is a mistake.  Entries like "90 kg bag" make no sense for such a variable.

Comment: Did you look at the documentation that came with that file? Relying on variable names alone is (almost) never enough. Your data "comes to life" when you know the exact questions behind those variables.